# iOS Fix search bar on top of the UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm adding search bar on table header and floating it in `scrollViewDidScroll` method, but when i scroll without click on search bar(i.e. i go to the view and do scroll) then search bar doesn't stay on top but it scroll up with table however once i click on search bar and click cancel button on search bar and then if i scroll the table, search bar stays on top.here is my code-

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame];
    [tableHeaderView addSubview:searchDisplayController.searchBar];
    [tableView setTableHeaderView:tableHeaderView];

    isSearching = NO;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    UISearchBar *searchBar = searchDisplayController.searchBar;
    CGRect searchBarFrame = searchBar.frame;

    if (isSearching) {
        searchBarFrame.origin.y = 0;
    } else {
        searchBarFrame.origin.y = MAX(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top);
    }

    searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = searchBarFrame;
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    isSearching = YES;
}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    isSearching = NO;
}
```

Note that I'm using `UITableViewController` sub class and don't want to change it to `UIViewController`.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I also using section header in this `UITableViewController`, in other `UITableViewController` there is no section header and this code working fine.Is this a problem with section header and table header together?

Comment: you should try add it to the section header

Comment: the tableHeader goes off the screen when you are scrolling, the section header is leaving the screen only when you start scrolling, and you are getting to the next section. If you have only 1 section the best way is to add the searchBar inside the section Header, otherwise you can't do it inside of the UItableViewController

Comment: Ok..i did that but now if i click on search bar, app crash without any error?

Comment: there is allways an error, just find it and show it to me

Comment: If you consider my answer as correct, please mark it as so.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason why your searchbar is scrolling with the table contents is that you have put it directly IN the table, thus making it a child header section of the table. and that section **ALWAYS** scrolls…

Here is how this this can be achieved. And it is actually quite simple. (The following example relies on Storyboard, but the mechanism is the same whatever you are using) :

1) Use a *UIVIewController* and **NOT** a *UITableViewController*

2) Add a *UITableView* as the **child** of the **parent** *UIView*

3) Add a *UISearchBarController* also as a **child** view of the *UIView*, **NOT as a child of the UITableView** (UITableView and UISearchController are siblings)

you should have the following layout :

[image]

EDIT : The important thing to remember is to put the *UISearchBarController* **ABOVE** the sibling *UITableView*. Otherwise you may see the *UITableView* **overlap** the *UISearchBarController* when the latter is **focused**.

EDIT 2 : BTW, if you are using AutoLayout, remember to set the TOP constraint of the tableView relative to the SearchBar…

Run it and admire the result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way to maintain the header of a tableView fixed

1- could use an UIViewController instead of UITableViewController.

2- add subview (UIView) for header.

3- and add another subview for the tableview.