# Tableview header is not scrollable even after changing the style to UITableViewStyleGrouped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4, xcode9

I am adding a searchBar to the header of my UITableView and want to be able to use it while user is scrolling through the the cells.

I have tried everything such as setting the style to **UITableViewStyleGrouped** but it didn't solve my problem.

here is the code

```
var searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

any reason why is the header stays at the stop?

Comment: @conarch not a helpful answer but it doesn't have anything to do with searchBar. The problem is with the header as it should scroll with while scrolling the contents

Comment: I assumed the search bar b/c that's the code you presented.  I mean, you've assigned it AS the table header.  It's the TABLE header, so it shouldn't scroll.

Comment: @conarch I am presenting the searchBar in the header view so even if I add a empty view I would get the same result .

Comment: Actually, I thoroughly apologize @Slyavash, I'm in a snarky mood and should not have commented.  I do think the table is behaving as intended, but I'm going to delete my earlier comments.  Sorry! :-(

Comment: @conarch haha its okay :D , but i think tableview is not behaving as it should have been because if you look at the section header it will scroll as you scroll to the next section

Comment: @ViniApp unfortunately thats for navigation bar and item

Comment: sorry, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702413/how-to-prevent-search-bar-from-disappearing-on-scroll-ios-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using iOS 11 then you can put the UISearchBar in the UINavigationBar using the following code. The UISearchBar will always be visible even if you scroll the UITableView.

```
class DishesTableViewController : UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false 
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're only looking for a programatic solution, but through Interface Builder you can put a Search Bar above the UITableView.

[image]